# Why does my Terminal window close automatically

Tags: gnome-terminal

My system is CentOS 6. X window is gnome 2.28.2

Why do I chick the terminal of Desktop that has been closed automatically. There before, I have set the options:

> profile preferences -> title and Command -> Command -> Run a custom command instead of my shell

Then, close the terminal, and open it again, it does't work as my description.

But, if I switch to another user to open the gnome-terminal it'll work

How do i fix it?

### Solution

- edit the file `$vi .gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml`
- set the custom_command option as

```
<entry name="custom_command" mtime="1368087662" type="string">
    <stringvalue>Default</stringvalue>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes because Terminal Profile changed. Correct this if Ubuntu.

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Write `gnome-terminal -e -ls` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Click  preferences
4. Check if Run a custom command is not checked and if so it must have a valid command also most imp click on top which says Run Command As Login...
5. Close and restart terminal and you are done.

Comment: He clearly stated that he wasn't using Ubuntu, but CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

This option has more followed duty:

`When command exits: Exit terminal.`

You just change it to `hold terminal open`.

Comment: i just enter the command ``` rvm use 1.9.2 --default```, how do i change it, i cannot open terminal now.